# TensorFlow Bidirectional GRU returns ValueError because of <supposedly> incorrect shape

Tags: tensorflow, bidirectional, labeling, gated-recurrent-unit

I'm implementing a bi-directional labeling GRU network (1 layer forward, 1 layer backward), using TensorFlow version 0.9. Upon the initialization of the model, TensorFlow initializes all the variables, creates the GRU cells and applies all regular transformations correctly, until it comes time to running the `tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn` function, where it throws a ValueError associated with an incorrectly shaped Tensor merging operation. Here's the code:

```
# Create the cells
with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
    self.char_gru_cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(char_hidden_size)
with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
    self.char_gru_cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(char_hidden_size)

# Set initial state of the cells to be zero
self._char_initial_state_fw = \
    self.char_gru_cell_fw.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
self._char_initial_state_bw = \
    self.char_gru_cell_bw.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

#         Size before: batch-chrpad-chrvocabsize
#          Size after: batch-chrvocabsize
chargruinput = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) \
    for input_ in tf.split(1, char_num_steps, chargruinput)]

# Run the bidirectional rnn and get the corner results
_, output_state_fw, output_state_bw = \
   tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(self.char_gru_cell_fw, 
                    self.char_gru_cell_bw, 
                    chargruinput, 
                    sequence_length=char_num_steps,
                    initial_state_fw=self._char_initial_state_fw,
                    initial_state_bw=self._char_initial_state_bw)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frontbackgru.py", line 409, in <module>
    main()
  File "frontbackgru.py", line 226, in main
    config=my_config)
  File "/home/xG/Code/4-RNN/1-simple-cnn-input-classifier/gru_model.py", line 265, in __init__
    initial_state_bw=self._char_initial_state_bw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 453, in bidirectional_rnn
    sequence_length, scope=fw_scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 156, in rnn
    state_size=cell.state_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 343, in _rnn_step
    _maybe_copy_some_through)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1331, in cond
    _, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(fn2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1230, in BuildCondBranch
    r = fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 317, in _maybe_copy_some_through
    lambda: _copy_some_through(new_output, new_state))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1331, in cond
    _, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(fn2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1230, in BuildCondBranch
    r = fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 317, in <lambda>
    lambda: _copy_some_through(new_output, new_state))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 298, in _copy_some_through
    return ([math_ops.select(copy_cond, zero_output, new_output)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1769, in select
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2262, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1702, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1578, in _SelectShape
    t_e_shape = t_e_shape.merge_with(c_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 570, in merge_with
    (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (32, 50) and () are not compatible
```

Now, the inputs into the `bidirectional_rnn` function are:

`self.char_gru_cell_fw`: This is a GRUCell instance initialized with an integer value of `char_hidden_size`, 50 in this case

`self.char_gru_cell_bw`: This is a GRUCell instance initialized with an integer value of `char_hidden_size`, 50 in this case

`chargruinput`: This is a list of length 30, containing Tensors of shape [`batch_size`,`charvocab`], which is [32,256] in this case

`sequence_length`: an integer representing the number of unrolled cells, `char_num_steps`, which is 30 in this case.

`initial_state_fw`: a zero-filled Tensor of the same shape as the state of the GRU, [32,50] in this case

`initial_state_bw`: a zero-filled Tensor of the same shape as the state of the GRU, [32,50] in this case

I tried looking through the modules that led to the ValueError exception being thrown, but there is a lot of low-level stuff going on that is most probably working fine, seeing how the CNN I was working on last week worked without any problems. This makes me think that before the low-level methods, something goes wrong in the `rnn` or `rnn_cell` library that I haven't used before.

It also seems strange because the error has to do with an empty shape (associated with a scalar instead of a Tensor I assume), but the only thing I am able to change that is scalar in the `bidirectional_rnn` function's arguments is the `sequence_length` argument. I have tried omitting it and using only initial states, and vice-versa, but the same error pops up.

Has anyone had a similar issue? My whole system is crippled by this, would love some feedback. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong - the argument `sequence_length` is actually supposed to be a list of integers of length `batch_size` for every batch, not an integer itself. Easy fix, thanks for playing :)